# Transactionscope error This platform does not support distributed transactions

Tags: c#, .net-core, transactionscope

I am using dontnet core 2.1

I am having the following error, How can I solve it?

> {System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This platform does not support
>   distributed transactions.    at
>   System.Transactions.Distributed.DistributedTransactionManager.GetDistributedTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetDistributedTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken)

My code

```
try
{
    using (var s= new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
   {

       // Running couple of insert / update and delete async operations
       s.Complete();
   }
 }
 catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
 {

 }
```

Note: If I remove `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` I end up having another exception `System.InvalidOperationException: A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created.`

Comment: Distributed transactions are not supported yet

Comment: The open GitHub issue is https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13532.

Comment: Does .net 7 support distributed transactions?